Is there language or tool that supports export lemma definition to LaTeX?
I'm looking for language / tools that supports export lemma definition to LaTeX. This does not means just printing code with pretty(colored) style in code block. What I want is, for example, suppose that I have following code:
theorem-about-f : {a b : R} -> int a b f is (b - a)
theorem-about-f = (...)

Then it is translated to LaTeX like this:
$$
theorem-about-f : \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}, \int_a^bf(x)dx=b-a
$$
Of course, I think this cannot be done without explicit mapping between LaTeX symbol and symbol in proof assistant.
Anyway, is there language feature or tool that translates the former to the latter, if sufficient information is given?

Mizar supports that too, but the program isn't contained in the standard distribution.

I think your best bet for this is Agda with lhs2tex and a good mapping of Unicode symbols to LaTeX commands. You can find a guide here: https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/literate-programming.html
In any language, the hard part is going to be defining a mapping between the name of the concept and the map notation. This is not possible to do automatically, and making such a mapping by hand requires significant time and effort.
With mixfix notation in Agda, you can at least start with a Unicode symbol that is fairly close to the math notation, so you don't need to define as many fixed rules. Then you can use lhs2tex to do some additional translations to clean up the notation.
In any case, I don't think any language is likely to be able to translate things consistently without significant manual touching up afterwards. Math notation tends to be messy and implicit, while dependent types require things to be exact. And mathematicians can't even agree on consistent notations, so having a unified notation that code can be extracted to is just a huge undertaking.

HOL4 and Isabelle/HOL both support mapping into LaTeX in automatic ways.  The former's support is documented in its DESCRIPTION manual.  It was used to write an ITP 2022 paper. The treatment of integrals isn't quite as nice as your example, and as the Agda example explains, there's usually a fair bit of tweaking required.

Note Isabelle's LaTeX support is not limited to a specific object logic (like Isabelle/HOL). A file called root.tex which is a part of a standard Isabelle session setup can be used to tweak LaTeX rendering of the proof document, in particular one can define how custom symbols should be rendered.
